# How can I integrate Flutter with iOS Media Control?

Tags: ios, flutter, audio

I'm currently using https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio and https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio_background, but it doesn't integrate with iOS Media Control. When iOS is in lockscreen, it doesn't show up what it's currently playing.

What options do I have here?

I've tried looking at https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio_background, but it doesn't seem to support it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) package